# VBA interpreter stops for apparently no reason

Tags: vba, excel

I am writting some function in Excel using VBA.
Here is my code :

```
 Function PresentValue2()

        Dim i As Double
        i = 1

        Dim coll As Collection

        coll.add i

        PresentValue2 = coll.Item(1)

  End Function
```

I made a break point and the intepreter just stops at the instruction `coll.add i` and the function return the value "#VALUE!"

Why is that?

I add the same problem with a Dynamic array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A collection is an object. You need to instantiate it before using it.  E.g.
Dim col1 as Collection
Set col1 = New Collection
col1.add "item"

Considering that your function seems to want to "persist" the value and check it this will still cause issues because you are instantiating a new collection each time this method is called.  You'll need to declare and instantiate the collection outside of your function and use it like this

```
Dim col1 as New Collection

Function PresentValue2 as Double
Dim i as Double
i = 1

col1.add i

'rest of your code here and return value
'....
End Function
```

Comment: Static is pretty nice too and so you don't need to late bind to the collection (an incy wincy bit slower) (use like `Sub blah():Static foo:If foo is nothing then set foo = New Bar():...rest of sub...`)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a **Set**:

```
Function PresentValue2()
    Dim i As Double
    i = 1
    Dim coll As Collection
    Set coll = New Collection
    coll.Add i
    PresentValue2 = coll.Item(1)
End Function
```